# No Python frame after running Apache server

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I have win11, Apache 2.4, mod_wsgi 4.9.4

I have problem:  with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'.
This problem occurs always after run Apache server, error is read from error log.

My httpd apache.conf file for Apache:

```
LoadFile "C:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310/python310.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310"

#WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp python-path="c:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310/lib/site-packages"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/exp_app"

    <Directory c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/exp_app>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/exp_app/app.wsgi"

    <Directory c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/exp_app>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Output of my error log:

```
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.465080 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5884:tid 344] AH00428: Parent: child process 21996 exited with status 1 -- Restarting.
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.496461 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 5884:tid 344] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.513172 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5884:tid 344] AH00455: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.2.0 mod_wsgi/4.9.4 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.513172 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5884:tid 344] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Jun 22 2022 09:58:15
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.513172 2023] [core:notice] [pid 5884:tid 344] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.514739 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5884:tid 344] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 20496
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.700090 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 20496:tid 336] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\pvachal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\pvachal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\pvachal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\pvachal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\pvachal\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00004a38 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Wed Mar 01 15:08:51.778876 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5884:tid 344] AH00430: Parent: Child process 20496 exited successfully.
```

Problem:

My wsgi file for connect to app flask instance:

```
#! C:/Users/pvachal/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe

import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/exp_app")

activate_this = "c:/users/pvachal/documents/projekty/exp_app/venv/scripts/activate_this.py"
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

from app import app as application
```

Mod_wsgi==4.9.4 via pip install is installed.
I tried set PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH but without results - same error  occured but PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH were set.
I think that something file has not activating environment. Is it true? Which file is it?
My biggest problem: I do not know where this error originates from. Do you know where are origins of this error? From which file? What Python file should have been run? How do I find out?

I get an error about no frame and ModuleNotFoundError even if Virtualhost is not written in httpd.
Where is focus of my problem?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This error originates from your Python script, not Apache or PHP.  Have you tested your Python alone to ensure it works?  *Then* trigger it via Apache and-or PHP.  Looks like the module is not found by Python (not installed or not in paths where Python looks for modules).  Research this error in a Python context.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But where I find this script? I don't know which script is running after start server. How does it work?

Comment: And... yes. Every script which I run is alright. But... I run every script in PyCharm. Maybe this is the problem - with directly running environment is not set.
I will find out and let you know.

Comment: So... problem is with mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd file.
In httpd.conf I let only LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/etc/etc/etc/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd" and this error occured.
Without LoadModule in other cases is ok.

Question is: how activate virutalenv for load this module? Obviously, this script is not recognized by Python. I tried create virutalenv in cmd and then activate this, after that I started apache but same problem, same error.

Any idea what Am I doing wrong?

Comment: My "progress" at work:
I set PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH to paths to make it work.
YES! Nothing works since.

I can't run any python script - same error: <no python frame>.

So... I will try fix wrong recognization with set paths and... we will see...

Comment: Finally... everything is OK. **SOLVED**
I fixed it by setting environment variable PYTHONHOME on value: c:/users/pvachal/appdata/local/programs/python/python310.
At first: this path was not set, so it could not work.
After set PYTHONHOME on c:/users/bla/bla/python310/lib that **did not work too**!
After that, path **without lib** worked.
After this rewrite, configuration in PyCharm does not work too but I finally fixed this.
So... my problem is solved. Mister Nic3500, Thank you very much for you help!